# MySQL database failing on count or sum and group by - not a duplicate of other threads

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, case

I truly have spent a week searching on here and playing around with answers / methods ...

db is MySQL 5.7 - no chance of going to MySQL8
It is a learning management database with a huge number of users.

This query searches their learning records and returns a (correct) 1 or 0 as to whether they have passed the course. Although it looks complex, THIS WORKS FINE!

```
SELECT 
CASE
    /* first check if the number of completions in the scorm tracking table is zero */
    WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.element = 'cmi.core.lesson_status' AND (t1.value = 'passed' OR t1.value = 'completed') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) = 0 THEN 0 
    /* modulus checks if it is a correctly completed course */
    WHEN (MOD(COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.element = 'cmi.core.lesson_status' AND (t1.value = 'passed' OR t1.value = 'completed') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END), (SELECT COUNT(sc9.id) AS scoes FROM mdl_scorm AS s9 LEFT JOIN mdl_scorm_scoes AS sc9 ON s9.id = sc9.scorm WHERE s9.course = c1.id AND sc9.launch = ''))) > 0 THEN 0
    ELSE 1
END AS learningresult
FROM mdl_user AS u1
LEFT JOIN mdl_scorm_scoes_track AS t1 ON t1.userid = u1.id
LEFT JOIN mdl_scorm AS s1  ON s1.id = t1.scormid
LEFT JOIN mdl_course AS c1 ON c1.id = s1.course
LEFT JOIN mdl_scorm_scoes AS sc1 ON s1.id = sc1.scorm
WHERE u1.id = 2446345 
AND sc1.launch = ''    
GROUP BY c1.id, t1.attempt
```

For an example user (id = 2446345 in this case), this will return a column called **learningresult** with a series of rows of either 1 or 0 to signify a pass or fail.

THE ABOVE CODE WORKS FINE, as I said ...

But, what I want to do is to **COUNT or SUM the learningresult column** to return the total number of courses they have passed.

I have tried

```
SELECT COUNT(
CASE
WHEN etc
```

and

```
SELECT SUM(
CASE
WHEN etc
```

Both return MySQL errors - code 1111 invalid use of group by function (and most errors with this code have the aggregate in the WHERE clause!!)

This is the NON WORKING CODE

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN refname=1  THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS complete  
FROM
    (SELECT CASE
    /* first check if the number of completions in the scorm tracking table is zero */
    WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.element = 'cmi.core.lesson_status' AND (t1.value = 'passed' OR t1.value = 'completed') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) = 0 THEN 0 
    /* modulus checks if it is a correctly completed course */
        WHEN (MOD(COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.element = 'cmi.core.lesson_status' AND (t1.value = 'passed' OR t1.value = 'completed') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END),
            (SELECT COUNT(sc9.id) AS scoes FROM mdl_scorm AS s9 LEFT JOIN mdl_scorm_scoes AS sc9 ON s9.id = sc9.scorm WHERE s9.course = c1.id AND sc9.launch = ''))) > 0 THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END AS refname
    FROM mdl_user AS u1
    LEFT JOIN mdl_scorm_scoes_track AS t1 ON t1.userid = u1.id
    LEFT JOIN mdl_scorm AS s1  ON s1.id = t1.scormid
    LEFT JOIN mdl_course AS c1 ON c1.id = s1.course
    LEFT JOIN mdl_scorm_scoes AS sc1 ON s1.id = sc1.scorm
    WHERE u1.id = 2446345
    AND sc1.launch = ''    
    GROUP BY c1.id, t1.attempt) AS tblname
```

I have looked at ROLLUP, but not made an example work with this code.

I have made this work as a subquery ... but this working query above is already a sub query of another, and having a sub sub query makes it impossible for the userid (2446345) to be dynamically generated by the outer query.

Many thanks for looking
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Just read about your problem.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
CASE
    /* first check if the number of completions in the scorm tracking table is zero */
    WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.element = 'cmi.core.lesson_status' AND (t1.value = 'passed' OR t1.value = 'completed') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) = 0 THEN 0 
    /* modulus checks if it is a correctly completed course */
    WHEN (MOD(COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.element = 'cmi.core.lesson_status' AND (t1.value = 'passed' OR t1.value = 'completed') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END), (SELECT COUNT(sc9.id) AS scoes FROM mdl_scorm AS s9 LEFT JOIN mdl_scorm_scoes AS sc9 ON s9.id = sc9.scorm WHERE s9.course = c1.id AND sc9.launch = ''))) > 0 THEN 0
    ELSE 1
END AS learningresult
FROM mdl_user AS u1
LEFT JOIN mdl_scorm_scoes_track AS t1 ON t1.userid = u1.id
LEFT JOIN mdl_scorm AS s1  ON s1.id = t1.scormid
LEFT JOIN mdl_course AS c1 ON c1.id = s1.course
LEFT JOIN mdl_scorm_scoes AS sc1 ON s1.id = sc1.scorm
WHERE u1.id = 2446345 
AND sc1.launch = ''    
GROUP BY c1.id, t1.attempt
```

Why don't you try like this?

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Hi. Thanks, but that counts up the ROWS that have been evaluated, not the 1s and 0s of the learningresult column.

Comment: If you want to retrieve rows that learningresult is 1 or 0, you can add a condition. like WHERE learningresult = "1".